# How to start odoo 11 under ubuntu?

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

i have Problem with odoo 11, he doesn't want to start, at first it worked fine,so I wrote this command :

```
systemctl status odoo.service
```

**So, i have this error :**

```
    odoo.service - Odoo Open Source ERP and CRM
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/odoo.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-06-28 10:28:38 PKT; 7s ago
      Process: 3256 ExecStart=/opt/odoo/odoo-bin --config /etc/odoo.conf --logfile /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log (code=exited, status=2)
     Main PID: 3256 (code=exited, status=2)

  juin 10 11:08:45 server-inprotec systemd[1]: Started Odoo Open Source ERP and CRM.
juin 10 11:08:46 server-inprotec odoo[3256]: Usage: odoo [options]
juin 10 11:08:46 server-inprotec odoo[3256]: odoo: error: The config file '/etc/odoo/odoo.conf' selected with -c/--config doesn't exi
juin 10 11:08:46 server-inprotec systemd[1]: odoo.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
juin 10 11:08:46 server-inprotec systemd[1]: odoo.service: Unit entered failed state.
juin 10 11:08:46 server-inprotec systemd[1]: odoo.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I looked for this error but I didn't find, I just found that the database Postgresql doesn't work, when I write its status in terminal :

```
systemctl status postgresql-9.5.main.service
```

**Result :**

```
    postgresql@9.5-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 9.5-main
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since lun. 2019-06-10 12:04:22 CET; 1h 59min ago
  Process: 2951 ExecStart=postgresql@%i --skip-systemctl-redirect %i start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

juin 10 12:04:22 server-inprotec systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 9.5-main...
juin 10 12:04:22 server-inprotec postgresql@9.5-main[2951]: Error: Config owner (inprotec:1000) and data owner (postgres:111) do not 
juin 10 12:04:22 server-inprotec systemd[1]: postgresql@9.5-main.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
juin 10 12:04:22 server-inprotec systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 9.5-main.
juin 10 12:04:22 server-inprotec systemd[1]: postgresql@9.5-main.service: Unit entered failed state.
juin 10 12:04:22 server-inprotec systemd[1]: postgresql@9.5-main.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

**, thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the file `/etc/odoo/odoo.conf` with a proper configuration, and then launch it again.

It should contain, among other things, settings to connect with a postgres server. Setting it up is another question, of course.

Comment: But, even i can't start postgresql with command : ``systemctl status postgresql@9.5-main.service``, it's always Failed

Comment: OK, but the question is not how to start postgres in ubuntu, it's how to start odoo. And Odoo can start with a remote Postgres too, so you should post a different question for that. :D